# How to force a full postback on a button created in code behind and displayed in an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am using an asp.net UpdatePanel that contains Button 1. On Button1 click, a string is created in code behind then sent back to the updatePanel. That string contains Button2 that should fire a postback to execute Button2_Click function. Unfortunately I haven't been able to execute a full postback on button 2 yet.

If I add Button2 as a PostBackTrigger control in the UpdatePanel on my aspx page I get an error that the control (Button2) is not found. This makes sense cause Buton2 is created by clicking Button1 in code behind and is not available on page load.

I'm trying to RegisterPostBackControl(Button2) on page load but again I get an error that Button2 doesn't exist in the current context.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

ASPX page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
   <fieldset>

   <div runat="server" id="DIV1">Testing...<br /></div>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" clientidmode="static"/> 

   <div runat="server" id="DIV2"></div>
   <asp:Label ID="DIV2_LABEL" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </fieldset>
</ContentTemplate>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(Button2);
    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DIV1_Html;
        DIV1_Html= DIV1.InnerHtml;

        DIV2.InnerHtml = DIV1_Html;
        DIV2.InnerHtml += "<input id='Button2' type='button' value='button' runat='server' OnClick='Button2_Click' />";

    }

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DIV2_LABEL.Text = "Testing button2";
    }
```

EDIT

Based on the advice below, I've added the button as follows:

Instead of:

```
 DIV2.InnerHtml += "<input id='Button2' type='button' value='button' runat='server' OnClick='Button2_Click' />";
```

I've amended the code as follows:

```
 Button Button2 = new Button();
 Button2.Text = "Add";
 Button2.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);
 PostBackTrigger pTrigger = new System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger() { ControlID = Button2.ID };
 UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(pTrigger);
 DIV2.Controls.Add(Button2);
```

BUT I'm still missing something because Button2_Click function is not fired when I click on the new button with NO error. ?????

Answer (score 1):

Since your Button2 is created in client-side, It's ID is not recognized by the updatePanel1.
You can create Button2 dynamically like this:

```
Button button2 = new Button();
PostBackTrigger pTrigger = new System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger() { ControlID = button2.ID };
updatePanel1.Triggers.Add(pTrigger);

DIV2.Controls.Add(button2);
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a little sample that you can use:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private bool ShowButton2()
    {
        return ViewState["createButton"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["createButton"];
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShowButton2())
            CreateButton();
    }

    void CreateButton()
    {
        Button Button2 = new Button();
        Button2.Text = "Add";
        Button2.ID = "button2";
        Button2.Click += Button2_Click;
        PostBackTrigger pTrigger = new System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger() { ControlID = Button2.ID };
        updatePanel1.Triggers.Add(pTrigger);
        DIV2.Controls.Add(Button2);
    }

    void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ShowButton2())
        {
            ViewState["createButton"] = true;
            CreateButton();
        }
    }

}
```

The view state is a flag for showing Button2 of course.

Comment: I've changed the code as suggested (plz see my edit up) but the server-side function (Button2_Click) is still not fired....No error on runtime.

Comment: If you have a Click event handler for button2 then you must recreate your dynamic controls in Page_Load every time.

Answer (score -1):

There is a property on the button called OnClientClick, you can use that to call a javascript which then navigate to your page.

Example:

In your apsx page

```
<script type="javascript">
function reloadPage() {
    window.location.href = '...';
}
```

In your code behind

```
DIV2.InnerHtml += "<input id='Button2' type='button' value='button' OnClick='ReloadPage()' />";
```

Comment: Just realised that Button2 is dynamically created. I've changed the code behind above.